# Vectorize High Frequency Data, Calculate Spread,

Tags: python, time-series, pandas

I have the data below saved as a pandas `dataframe`. With this data, I would like to calculate the bid ask spread for a specific second. However, as you can see there are many times more asks than bids and vice versa. So my goal is to do the following: I would like to take only data such that it is a bid followed by an ask, or an ask followed by the bid for the same timestamp and then calculate the spread and how many spreads there were.

In the below data, it would look like the following, I would take row 1 and row 2, and calculate the spread which is 0. Then I would take row 3 and row 4 and have a spread of 2.

```
        time quote   price  volume
0   07:00:00     B  3950.5       5
1   07:00:00     B  3950.0       4
2   07:00:00     A  3950.0       7
3   07:00:00     B  3948.0      17
4   07:00:00     A  3950.0      20
5   07:00:00     A  3950.0      31
6   07:00:00     A  3950.0      44
7   07:00:00     A  3950.0      57
8   07:00:00     A  3950.0      67
9   07:00:00     A  3950.0      57
10  07:00:00     A  3950.0      67
11  07:00:00     A  3950.0      80
12  07:00:00     A  3950.0      90
13  07:00:00     A  3950.0      99
14  07:00:01     B  3948.0      15
15  07:00:01     A  3950.0      89
16  07:00:01     A  3949.5       1
17  07:00:02     A  3950.0      89
18  07:00:03     B  3948.0      12
19  07:00:03     A  3949.0       1
20  07:00:03     B  3948.0       9
21  07:00:03     B  3948.5       4
22  07:00:04     A  3949.5       5
23  07:00:04     B  3948.5       2
24  07:00:05     B  3948.5       1
```

This is my desired output:

```
       time spread num_spread
   07:00:00      2          2 
   07:00:01      2          1  
   07:00:03      1          1
   07:00:04      1          1
```

Comment: You'll first need to split the data by timestamp, then from there if you were to treat it as an array shift an element from the array to use as comparison if the quote type is equal then continue and shift a new element repeat until != then calculate spread.  I don't know where your `num_spread` comes from.

Comment: that's exactly what i thought. i did groupby first but an array shift to compare is going to be extremely slow. i am trying to vectorize this. so far i have come up with assigning 1 to B and -1 to A. taking the difference in the array between itself and 1 lag will work except for the case where it is B A B A B A where it will yield 0 0 0 0 0. I can fix this by looping but the whole point was to vectorize this to minimize computation time. num_spread comes from the amount of spreads that were calculated in that time period

Comment: I don't believe you can avoid iteration 100% with what you are trying to do. You can possibly duplicate the `quote` column twice shifting it  by one each direction and apply it to your dataset to create a pivot table based on entries where `quote` is != to `quote_next` and `quote_prev`.

Comment: it seems to work using a smart number theory argument but it seems like it is slower than iteration because it involves powers and vector multiplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('/tmp/ba.data') as dataF:
    oldk, oldsub = None, None
    for key, subi in groupby(map(str.split,dataF), lambda x: (x[1],x[2])):
        if oldk == None:
            oldk, oldsub = key, list(subi)
        else:       
            newsub = list(subi)
            print ' '.join(oldk), '->', ' '.join(key), float(oldsub[-1][3])-float(newsub[0][3])
            oldk, oldsub = None, None
```

gets this

```
07:00:00 B -> 07:00:00 A 0.0
07:00:00 B -> 07:00:00 A -2.0
07:00:01 B -> 07:00:01 A -2.0
07:00:02 A -> 07:00:03 B 2.0
07:00:03 A -> 07:00:03 B 1.0
07:00:04 A -> 07:00:04 B 1.0
```

if you change

```
if oldk == None:
```

to

```
if oldk == None or oldk[0] != key[0]:
```

you`ll get

```
07:00:00 B -> 07:00:00 A 0.0
07:00:00 B -> 07:00:00 A -2.0
07:00:01 B -> 07:00:01 A -2.0
07:00:03 B -> 07:00:03 A -1.0
07:00:04 A -> 07:00:04 B 1.0
```